# Adding an extra two variables to a count simulator function

Tags: javascript, gsap

I've created the following fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/jnoweb/v421zzbe/2/

At the moment it has one variable which makes all three IDs count up to 20:

```
  var game = {score:0},

scoreDisplay = [
  document.getElementById("score1"),
  document.getElementById("score2"),
  document.getElementById("score3")];

function add20() {
  TweenLite.to(game, 1, {score:"+=20", roundProps:"score", onUpdate:updateHandler, ease:Linear.easeNone});
}

function updateHandler() {
  scoreDisplay.forEach(function(display) {
    display.innerHTML = game.score;
  });
}

add20();
```

I want to change this so that each ID counts to a different value, for example 16, 18 and 20!

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the more elegant, generic, configurable solution.

```js
  function ScoreDisplay(id, increment) {
    this.elm = document.getElementById(id);
    this.inc = increment;
    this.game = {score: 0};
  }
  
  ScoreDisplay.prototype = {
     update: function(){
        this.elm.innerHTML = this.game.score;
     }
  };
  
  var scoreDisplay = [];
  scoreDisplay.push(new ScoreDisplay('score1', 16));
  scoreDisplay.push(new ScoreDisplay('score2', 18));
  scoreDisplay.push(new ScoreDisplay('score3', 20));

    function addScore() {
      scoreDisplay.forEach(function(sd) {
      TweenLite.to(sd.game, 1, {score: "+=" + sd.inc, roundProps:"score", onUpdate:sd.update.bind(sd), ease:Linear.easeNone});
      });
    }

    addScore();
```

```css
 #score1 {
            position: relative;
            font-size: 30px;
            font-weight: bold;
            padding: 20px;
            text-align: center;
            background-color: transparent;
            color: $white;
            border-radius: 20px 20px;
            top: -11px;
            left: -42px;
          }
          #score2 {
            position: relative;
            font-size: 30px;
            font-weight: bold;
            padding: 20px;
            text-align: center;
            background-color: transparent;
            color: $white;
            border-radius: 20px 20px;
            top: -11px;
            left: -42px;
          }

          #score3 {
            position: relative;
            font-size: 30px;
            font-weight: bold;
            padding: 20px;
            text-align: center;
            background-color: transparent;
            color: $white;
            border-radius: 20px 20px;
            top: -11px;
            left: -42px;
          }
```

```html
<!--TweenLite/TweenMax GSAP-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/plugins/CSSPlugin.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/easing/EasePack.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/TweenLite.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/TimelineLite.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/plugins/RoundPropsPlugin.min.js"></script>

      <div id="prodArrow"></div>
      <div id="prodCount">
        <div id="score1"></div>
          
      </div>

      <div id="testArrow"></div>
      <div id="testCount">
        <div id="score2"></div>

      </div>

      <div id="devArrow"></div>
      <div id="devCount">
        <div id="score3"></div>

      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var game = {
      score1: 0,
      score2: 0,
      score3: 0
  },

scoreDisplay = [
  document.getElementById("score1"),
  document.getElementById("score2"),
  document.getElementById("score3")
];

function add(scoreIndex, numToAdd) {
  TweenLite.to(game, 1, {score:("+="+numToAdd), roundProps: ("score" + scoreIndex), onUpdate:updateHandler, ease:Linear.easeNone});
}

function updateHandler() {
  scoreDisplay.forEach(function(display, i) {
     var key = ("score" + (i+1))
     display.innerHTML = game[key];
  });
}

add(1 , 16); 
add(2 , 18); 
add(3 , 20);
```

Comment: Hmmm, I've tried the above in the fiddle, but they don't work!

Comment: I don't know what TweenLite is so that part may be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

What about this ?

```
  var game = {
    score1:0,
    score2:0,
    score3:0
  },

    scoreDisplay = [
      document.getElementById("score1"),
      document.getElementById("score2"),
      document.getElementById("score3")];

    function add20() {
      TweenLite.to(game, 1, {score1:"+=16", score2:"+=18", score3:"+=20", roundProps:"score", onUpdate:updateHandler, ease:Linear.easeNone});
    }

    function updateHandler() {
      scoreDisplay.forEach(function(display, key) {
        var score = scoreDisplay[key].id;
        display.innerHTML = game[score];
      });
    }

    add20();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hundma4g/